# Numpy no module/attribute when importing other packages depending on it

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, jupyter, miniconda

On 2 distinct independent systems, I have Anaconda/Miniconda. On my default virtual environment on either one, since 2018-8-15, when I import pandas or matplotlib, I get errors `module 'numpy' has no attribute '__version__'` and `module 'numpy' has no attribute 'square'`, respectively.

An update to conda or one of the modules may have done damage, but I haven't been able to figure out. The computers, one is a Mac and one a Windows PC. The only common features are that I use the Jupyter Notebook environment on both systems, both are default environments, both may have deep learning packages installed on them (as opposed to the other environments which are still functioning well), and I've been using the Jupyter Notebook environment to code on both.

Has anyone come across this problem? Is there a solution? Is it waiting for a fix update?

Comment: If you named a file `numpy.py`, don't do that.

Comment: That's a good point. I haven't done it but will search; maybe last update, they added some such thing

Comment: @hafniate Who is the "they"? Anaconda, Pandas, Jupyter, etc. definitely don't have such a file. The question is whether your code does.

Comment: I haven't created any numpy.py or any folder named like that. I searched for both numpy.py and numpy folders with __init__.py in them, but nothing odd came up

Comment: how about kgboost, tensorflow, or keras, of any recent update from them?

Comment: `import numpy; print(numpy.__file__)` and you'll probably find some `numpy.py` file or `numpy` directory you created and forgot about.

Comment: I cannot use .__file__ on the affecting numpy on the affected env, but when I run `help(numpy)`, I get:
    Help on package numpy: \n
    NAME \n
        numpy \n
    PACKAGE CONTENTS \n
        _mklinit \n
        conftest \n
        random_intel (package) \n
        tests (package) \n
    FILE \n
        (built-in) \n

Comment: That `random_intel` sounds like you have a bad install of the [Intel Distribution for Python](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2016/06/15/faster-random-number-generation-in-intel-distribution-for-python).

Comment: I compared the folders of numpy in the respective virtual envs, and their complex hierarchies look quite different; also in each there are 2 folders (numpy and numpy...). I think I'll wait for a fix now, which I think may come in a future release of one of the packages.

Comment: xgboost*. By the way, has anyone else encountered something like this?

Comment: I cloned the environment. The clone works perfectly well!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue and I think it is related to a broken install. I fixed mine with `conda update --all`. But I guess you can fix it with uninstalling numpy and reinstalling it back.